# Makefile notations for variables: $${var} ${var} $(var)

Tags: makefile

what are the difference between `$${var}` `${var}` `$(var)`

```
components = apple orange bananas
.PHONY run-fruits
        for fruit in $(fruits); do \
                DIR=${TOPDIR}/$${fruit} FRUIT=$${fruit} $(MAKE) -C ${TOOLDIR}/makefiles
        done
```

as you can tell, `$(MAKE)` is parentheses, `${TOPDIR}` and `${TOOLDIR}` are brackets and there is double dollar signs for fruit `$${fruit}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference).

`$(X)` and `${X}` are equivalent.

`$$` expands to `$` so `$${X}` expands to `${X}`, which is a useful trick when you want to postpone evaluation of a variable.

```
foo:
    echo $SHELL_VARIABLE  # fails
    echo $$SHELL_VARIABLE # works as intended
```

The first command fails because Make sees `$S`, evaluates it and expands it to nothing (unless you have defined `S` as a Make variable), and passes "echo HELL_VARIABLE" to the shell. The second command works because Make turns `$$` into `$` and passes "echo $SHELL_VARIABLE" to the shell. This also comes up in [recipe templates](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) and [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), but those are advanced topics.

Comment: hmm then i dont understand why we would mix and match $(X) and ${X} why not just pick on and be consistent? Is there some styling guide or something for differentiate when to use, if functionally its the same?

Comment: @ealeon: I always use parentheses. I know of no style convention that calls for braces.

Comment: I mostly use the brace notation, but I'm in a (probably rather small) minority.  Consistency is more important than which of the two notations is used.

Comment: Note that `${var}` is compatible with the shell. You can thus write a text file containing lines like `var1=foo`, `var2=${var1}bar`... and include it in a Makefile or source it from the shell. It is sometimes handy to have the same script parsed by two different tools as two different languages.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Interesting! I didn't know that.